# How does one measure the state probabilities of a 2 level Hydrogen atom qubit?

Tags: quantum-information, measurements, quantum-computer

I have been struggling with trying to understand how one could measure the probabilities of a superimposed Hydrogen atom's two energy states. Say the atom is in a superimposed state: Psi = a|0> + b|1>, and the a & b have been altered by a quantum algorithm, how can one do repeated measurements to estimate the |a|^2 and 
|b|^2?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the photon emitted by the hydrogen atom.

In a general case, if you have any 2 level system you can couple it to a scalar field, and look at the excitation of a scalar field to say something about the probabilities of individual states.

Comment: Why are you treating photons as a scalar field here?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not intend that, I meant to say in general if you have a 2 level system you can couple it to a scalar field, to study superposition states. I will edit the answer.

Comment: That's what I thought and I didn't imply that you don't know better. :-)

Comment: Thanks Prathyush, .. That's exactly what I have been pursuing, especially the James-Cumming's Model, but I need more specific info on how the probabilities are measured.

Comment: @JulianBliar Hmm... I don't know if I can help you, Maybe you if you pose a specific question. You simply look at a large ensemble of situations and  designed to be in a superposition state see how many times you can see an emitted photon.